# How to commit each DB transaction in mapping node in IIB Toolkit?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have a JSON body of Array type. Now each body will be inserted into DB one by one. There is constraint to use mapping node only as it is having GUI. But in mapping node, I cannot change the transaction from automatic to any other value. As a result when first body is inserted into DB and second one is failed, first one is also getting rolled back. How to design the mapping node such a way that when 1st is successful, it will be committed too? or if the 1st is failed, second will also be attempted to be inserted?

here is the JSON request of atleast 2 elements' array:

```
[
    {
        "batch_id": 2019,
        "trx_no": "test",
        "sys_ref_no": "test",
        "trx_line_num": 1,
        "trx_start_date": "test",
        "trx_post_on_date": "test",
        "trx_post_on_date_dr": "06-APR-20",
        "company_code": "test",
        "company_id": 1,
        "shop_num": "test",
        "shop_id": 1,
        "pos_num": "test",
        "pos_id": 1,
        "tax_type": "test",
        "tax_code": "test",
        "tax_rate": 1,
        "currency_code": "test",
        "currency_id": 1,
        "tax_amt": 1,
        "tax_id": 1,
        "tax_base_amt": 1,
        "tax_exchange_rate": 1,
        "tax_exchange_date": "test",
        "tax_exchange_type": "test",
        "status": "test",
        "error_message": "test",
        "creation_date": "06-APR-20",
        "created_by": 1,
        "last_update_date": "06-APR-20",
        "last_update_by": 1,
        "data_source": "test",
        "request_id": 1,
        "billing_intf_flag": "test",
        "n_attribute1": 1,
        "n_attribute2": 1,
        "n_attribute3": 1,
        "c_attribute1": "test",
        "c_attribute2": "test",
        "c_attribute3": "test",
        "d_attribute1": "test",
        "d_attribute2": "test",
        "d_attribute3": "test",
        "d_attribute1_dr": "06-APR-20",
        "d_attribute2_dr": "06-APR-20",
        "d_attribute3_dr": "06-APR-20"
    },
    {
        "batch_id": 2020,
        "trx_no": "test",
        "sys_ref_no": "test",
        "trx_line_num": 1,
        "trx_start_date": "test",
        "trx_post_on_date": "test",
        "trx_post_on_date_dr": "06-APR-20",
        "company_code": "test",
        "company_id": 1,
        "shop_num": "test",
        "shop_id": 1,
        "pos_num": "test",
        "pos_id": 1,
        "tax_type": "test",
        "tax_code": "test",
        "tax_rate": 1,
        "currency_code": "test",
        "currency_id": 1,
        "tax_amt": 1,
        "tax_id": 1,
        "tax_base_amt": 1,
        "tax_exchange_rate": 1,
        "tax_exchange_date": "test",
        "tax_exchange_type": "test",
        "status": "test",
        "error_message": "test",
        "creation_date": "06-APR-20",
        "created_by": 1,
        "last_update_date": "06-APR-20",
        "last_update_by": 1,
        "data_source": "test",
        "request_id": 1,
        "billing_intf_flag": "test",
        "n_attribute1": 1,
        "n_attribute2": 1,
        "n_attribute3": 1,
        "c_attribute1": "test",
        "c_attribute2": "test",
        "c_attribute3": "test",
        "d_attribute1": "test",
        "d_attribute2": "test",
        "d_attribute3": "test",
        "d_attribute1_dr": "06-APR-20",
        "d_attribute2_dr": "06-APR-20",
        "d_attribute3_dr": "06-APR-20"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is constraint to use mapping node only as it is having GUI.

This problem would be simple to solve using a Compute node and a small amount of ESQL. It is (as far as I know) impossible using the Mapping node. So either that constraint gets relaxed, or the requirement for independent transactions has to be removed.

In general, it is a bad idea to make rigid rules about which IIB transformation language to use, because it leads to awkward situations like this one. It's OK to have a *preferred* language or a *default* language, as long as other languages are allowed when it makes sense. Your situation is actually slightly unusual. It is more common (but still unwise) for ESQL to be the one-and-only-allowed-language!

Comment: Thanks Kimbert. Actually, this is end user's recommendation to use such coding which is having GUI, which is logical from production maintenance perspective. But honestly, it's IIB's drawback that they couldn't back ESQL with GUIs. :(

Comment: I hear you, but my advice remains exactly the same. And it is not particularly unusual for a procedural language to be capable of things that a graphical mapping language cannot do.

Comment: Thanks Kimbert 4 the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Since don't want to process this JSON as single unit of work i.e. either commit to db or rollback, you could divide the work into two separate message flows. The first message flow splits the input JSON with multiple childs into individual JSON with only one node. Feed this individual JSON node(body) to the next message flow which uses the mapping node to insert in the database. This way you can workaround your constraint of using mapping node.

Comment: Little more elaborate, friend. Two message flows I understood. 1st one will be having a for-each in mapping node to split the message. 2nd one will insert splitted message to DB and callback 1st flow. Now when the control comes to 1st flow's mapping node for the second time, will the for-each RESTART from beginning or start from 2nd part of the message?

Comment: The first flows job is just to split the large JSON into individual JSON's. For example, in your question, you have a sample JSON which has two child nodes with batch id 2019 and 2020. Each batch id should separate out as one JSON message, so your output of the first flow will be two JSON messages pushed to a queue. The second flow picks messages from this queue and uses your mapping node to do inserts. This way your solution would scale for even large message and at the same time meet your need of even if one JSON batch id fails to insert in DB, others shouldn't get impacted.

Comment: Himadri - I would like to get your feedback. Did my answer help you ?

Comment: Sorry for answering little late, friend. Yes it's helpful definitely. But the architecture you are suggesting is asynchronous. That way client wont get real time immediate response. Hence I convinced stake holders for ESQL with sync architecture. Very bad to see that Mapping node has limited option and in ESQL, you need to write code, there's no GUI. There are atleast 13 tables I need to insert data in more or less 50 odd columns. imagine my situation while mapping all columns and values in ESQL.

Comment: What is the _meaning_ of this 'real time response' for the client? Why does it have to be sychronous. Does it matter if the client gets a response before all of the database operations have completed?